# Display popup after PHP fread finishes

Tags: php, javascript, fwrite, fread, fsockopen

I want to issue a popup or something to remind users to perform a second action after the first action is done. The first action is

```
fwrite($fp, $str);
$read = fread($fp, 16);
$read = explode(";", $read);
if ($read[0] != "OK") {
    echo "Write Error";
    fclose($fp);
} else {
    $send = substr($str, 3);
    verification($send, $fp);
}
```

and the second action is `verification()`.

Before the `verification()`, I want to make something that reminds user that the first action is finished. Either a popup or something like that.

Comment: Your question is not clear, but you seems to need JavaScript for this. Are you already using js/ajax to call this php script?

Comment: thats the point, im not too familiar with javascript/ajax :D

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to write a javascript alert:

```
<script>window.alert('insert reminder here');</script>
```

After that, use php's `flush()` command to output everything up to that point to the browser, but you may have difficulty doing that before completing the if statement.

Comment: i already try this method, but like thReality says, the javascript run after php script interpreted. i think i'll try ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use javascript in PHP,html and javascript will run after php script is interpreted.
To do what you want you must place verification() in another page,alert after your first action then redirect to another page which do verification().

Comment: yeah, i'll try to use this method first before learning ajax.